# nested EJB not rolling back

Tags: java, ejb, jta, transactional

Simple application service throws exception:

```
@Stateless
public class AppService {

    @Inject
    private Repository repo;
    @Inject
    private AppService2 service2;

    public void createFoo(String name) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(repo.nextIdentity(), name);
        repo.save(foo);
    //    service2.createBar(name);
        throw new RuntimeException("asdf");
    }
}
```

`Repository` is also `@Stateless` and `AppService2` is similiar to `AppService`.

When I throw exception like above the `foo` is rolled back - everything is ok. But when I call another service (the commented), the `bar` is not persisted into DB but `foo` is persisted.

Why `foo` is not rolled back after calling another service?

**EDIT**

I found that AppService2 is making a checking query to DB before saving `bar`

```
public void createBar(String name) {
    if (repo.find(name) != null)
        ...
    Bar bar = new Bar(repo.nextIdentity(), name);
    repo.save(bar);
}
```

and this query is interrupting transaction. When I set @TransactionAttribute on this method

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
public Bar find(String name) {}
```

it resolves the problem.

Could you explain how it works?

Is this the right way or is there another?